# Passing dynamic onChange listener to children

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a stateful component that holds some state

```
state={
  name:'',
  age:'',
  occupation:''
}
```

And a function to update the state onChange listener

```
onValueChange = (key, event) => {
  this.setState({ [key]: event.target.value });
};
```

I pass the state and function down to child as props

<`ComponentA {...this.state} changed={this.onValueChange}>`

Inside my component B which is a child of A I want to programatically create inputs based on given props and change the state by invoking that function every time user types in input.

```
<ComponentB>

{  Object.entries(this.props)
    .filter(
      prop =>
        prop[0] !== 'changed'
    )
    .map(propName => (
      <Input
        key={propName}
        label={propName[0]}
        value={propName[1]}
        onValueChange={this.props.changed(propName[0])}
      />
    ))}

  </ComponentB>
```

My Input component just renders the following

```
  <input
     onChange={this.props.onValueChange}
     value={this.props.value}
     type={this.props.type}
     placeholder="&nbsp;"
   />
```

Can't make it work for some reason.
Thanks for any help!

Comment: Try to write `onValueChange={event => this.props.changed(propName[0], event)}` instead.

Comment: It works, but for some reason input loses focus after each keystroke.

Comment: Great. That's because the `propName` changes every render, so the `key` changes and React creates an entirely new component.

Comment: Ah, I see, can I solve that somehow so my inputs behave normally, but rendered dynamically?

Comment: You should be able to use `key={propName[0]}`

Comment: Missed that, thanks! Works as expected now, will you provide a short answer, so I can upvote and close?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently invoking `this.props.changed` straight away on render by writing `onValueChange={this.props.changed(propName[0])}`. Instead of invoking it on render you should give it a function to call when `onValueChange` occurs instead.

You also want to give the `Input` a unique `key` prop that will not change between state updates, so that React doesn't create an entirely new component every time and you e.g. lose focus of the `input`. You can use `propName[0]` instead, which will be unique.

```
<Input
  key={propName[0]}
  label={propName[0]}
  value={propName[1]}
  onValueChange={event => this.props.changed(propName[0], event)}
/>
```